# How to change UI elements from a class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, class, user-interface

So the situation is that I have a bluetooth class where I get some values, I want to display those values inside the UI, but for some reason I can't figure out how to do it. In swift I would do it with an observable object, but in Kotlin I couldnt really find something similar, or I could at least not get it to work. Is there an easy way to do this (setting UI from a class?) and is there something special I have to do inside the class?

I was quite dumbfounded by how difficult it is / how hard it is to find how to do it. I have things like and more

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.NewText)
textView.text = "Changed from class"
```

I also tried setting that inside

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
}
```

and inside

```
runOnUiThread{}
```

both crashed!
I have tried doing somethings with binding and researched quite a bit and I just can't figure it out.
I saw some thing with something called kapt, but that is old I Believe?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be poor *separation of concerns* to change UI from a BT helper class. Why should it have to know about specific views on a specific screen? You should expose a callback (listener interface), Flow, or Android LiveData. Use this to publish results and the UI class (Activity or Fragment) can observe the changes on the main thread and update its own views.

Comment: We’d have to see more code and your stack trace to tell you what’s making your current code crash.